# MP28167-A DC-DC converter recommends a resistor T-network in feedback loop

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc-dc-converter, voltage-divider, feedback, frequency-response

I am designing a DC-DC buck-boost converter using the MP28167-A, and the [datasheet](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP28167GQ-A/document_id/9621/) contains this section:

[image: datasheet exerpt]

I understand the need for a resistor divider such that the closed-loop control regulates the voltage at the center tap to \$V_{ref}\$, but why do they recommend the addition of \$R_T\$ and how are the recommended values calculated?

I suspect this has something to do with loop stability, and ensuring sufficient phase margin in light load conditions maybe? I know it is often recommended to add a capacitor in parallel with \$R_1\$.

Since my application does not require high efficiency at light load, can I reduce \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ for a higher current through the resistor divider, without worrying about loop stability?

Comment: Feedback current is 10nA. I think you can do what you want, it will be fine. Just in case keep a 0R for RT, so if we are all wrong, you have a way of fixing it

Comment: @TQQQ We? I for one would certainly not recommend such a step.

Comment: Tim Williams then you cannot join 

Answer (score 2):

Usually a series resistor is added, or the Thevenin resistance of the divider designed to suit, when there is internal compensation on the pin.

Unfortunately, your reading of the datasheet is correct: it does not say what the purpose is.  The correct answer is to ask the manufacturer; we cannot help you here, I'm afraid.  The remainder of this answer explains this conclusion in a bit more detail.

---

Usually, clues are found in the block diagram:

[image]

however, no connections are shown around the Error Amplifier (well, `PG`, but that will be a comparator input, not a current path).  The EA output, `COMP`, is referred to in text, and seems to be a control voltage, so EA must be an op-amp with internal compensation.

To be of the type where series resistance into `FB` is required, there would be a R+C feedback network from `COMP` to `FB`, and therefore the loop gain is proportional to the divider Thevenin resistance.

Transconductance amps are also very popular, and do not require feedback to the `FB` pin; only an R+C from `COMP` to `GND` would be used in that case.  It isn't clear if this is what they chose, either, but it would not explain the series resistor.

There are 11 search results for "compensat" in the datasheet, all to do with the I2C drop compensation feature.

`COMP` voltage is mentioned on p.18, with no explanation of how it arrives at that voltage (i.e., it must be varying with time, dependent on internal compensation).

Other pins/functions are discussed on p.20+, but not `FB`.

On p.28, RT is given in a figure and table, and not mentioned in the text at all.

On the product page, 
https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/mp28167-a.html 
there doesn't seem to be any further clues: no device- or family-specific app notes, no additional information in the eval board, no references or resources.

I would recommend using the resistor values, or Thevenin equivalents, as given.

As for why they use three rather than two resistors: perhaps due to leakage and tolerance, they opted for smaller value resistors; megohm values tend to get slightly more expensive in precision (1%) tolerance, and are more sensitive to leakage on the board (e.g. due to flux residue, dust contamination, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

The idea appears to be to keep the gain of the "internally compensated" error amplifier at some level to provide adequate response (e.g. recovery time and dynamic overshoot/undershoot amount).

Normally we use a divider and feed it to the comparator's input directly:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq9oKS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now at AC analysis, because Vref node will be ground, the R2 resistor will be shorted therefore only R1 will appear in the transfer function:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAJ02U.png)</sup>

---

Adding series resistor will effectively increase the resistance seen by the inverting input. If you take the Thevenin equivalent of the network it'll be easier to see:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPg5Qd.png)</sup>

As can be seen above, the bottom-side resistor is not shorted thanks to the RT so the effective resistance is increased. This changes the gain of the amplifier and, apparently, ensures better stability and response.

According to the table given in the datasheet, for 5V output for example, the Thevenin resistance becomes ~890k but without RT it'd be only 430k.

So, as long as you bring enough resistance to the pin you'll be fine. This means that, for 5V for example, if you make the R1 ~890k and choose the low-side resistor accordingly (to bring ~1V at 5V output, i.e. 220~223k) you won't need the RT resistor. You should take the FB input current into account, of course.

---

One side note here: Because the amplifier is internally compensated, as far as I understood, the resistance values are chosen for "optimum" response times and overshoot/undershoot amounts. Because, for 20V output, the total resistance becomes much lower (200k) so keeping it high just like in 5V and 12V may cause worse response, apparently. Decreasing the total resistance here should increase the response speed, if I understood here correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, it is a bit strange and they really could spend a few words about it in the datasheet.
Now, everything we can do is guess.

I doubt that is related to compensation, although it could be some kind of compensation, if Rt is forming an RC with internal parasitic capacity of the FB pin.

It is also possible that the impedance of the FB pin is relatively low, (that could be also due to PG and OVP circuit, which is also connected to FB pin, in parallel with error amp), so could it impact the value of the lower divider resistor (R2). On the other hand, I see that it is not mentioned in the calculation.

Another possibility is that it only limits the current going to FB pin during the transient spikes, etc.

Tbh, in every case, I would stick to the rubbish datasheet values or even better, consider using another DC/DC converter.